# Button on Master page when clicked get values from controls on content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a button on a Master page and when it is clicked it calls a method on the  master page which requires several parameters. The values for the parameters are stored in text boxes and drop down lists on both the master page and the content page. I can get the values from the controls on the master page, but I am not sure how to retrieve the values from the controls on the content page.

I have spent the last day looking at various answers on here and on other sites, but have nor found a solution that works for me.

I have also seen answers that suggest putting the buttons on the control page, but that would mean duplicating code on at least 12 pages and I really dont want to have to go down that route unless I have to.

I forgot to say that I am already using the Master reference tag in the content page.

**EDIT**

If I create a class and set values in the content page, what would be the best way to retrieve the values in the master page. Assuming that would be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a public method like `SetYourDropdownValue(string val)` to your master page.
In the load-eventhandler from the control page you hand over the selected value from the dropdown to your master page.

```
MyMainPage m = (MyMainPage)Master;
m.SetYourDropdownValue("your value");
```

There is an alternative way tho: [Master Pages Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx).

You can set following reference tag in your control page markup:

```
<%@ MasterType virtualPath="~/MasterPage.master"%>
```

Then it will be even easier:

```
Master.SetYourDropdownValue("your value");
```

In the SetYourDropdownValue-Method you save the value to a variable.
On the click eventhandler in your master page, you can then retreive the value from your variable.

Instead of passing a string you could also pass one or more controls, so you would just have to save the reference to it, instead of saving a value.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention that I have set the reference tag already. I will give your solution a try and let you know how I get on

Comment: Your suggestion has given me some more ideas and I am looking at using a class or failing that session variables